# Biblioteca Java para Nota Fiscal Eletrônica (NFe) brasileira

Tags: java, código-aberto, brasil, nfe

Desenvolvo um sistema de gerenciamento empresarial há algum tempo. Estou precisando adicionar ao mesmo a funcionalidade de emissão de nota fiscal eletrônica no padrão brasileiro.

Existe alguma biblioteca Java bem testada e de preferência livre e de código aberto que me ajude com isso?

Comment: E alguma em C sabem se existe?

Answer (score 23):

Sei do [jNFE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jnfe/) e do [JeNiFEr](http://jenifer.sourceforge.net/). Não usei nenhum dos dois, mas boto mais fé no Jenifer. No github têm também o [Caelum-Stella](https://github.com/caelum/caelum-stella), que tem um módulo NFe, ainda que não documentado na wiki.

Alias, documentação é o que não falta nesses projetos: não falta o que fazer em relação à documentação! :)

Comment: Como esta a desenvoltura desses projetos? Principalmente da Caelum-Stella, alguns alguns como o jNFE foram descontinuados.

Answer (score 9):

Sou um dos desenvolvedores de uma biblioteca java para NFe 3.10, tem varias funcionalidades além do envio de lote.
Ela possui diversos testes de unidade (+1000) além de possuir validações de valores a nível de setter e validar contra um xsd no envio de lote, além da preocupação em ser fácil de utilizar :)

Você precisa de uma classe de configuracão e o Facade da biblioteca para comunicar com a Sefaz.

```
NFStatusServicoConsultaRetorno retorno = new WSFacade(config).consultaStatus(NFUnidadeFederativa.SC);
System.out.println(retorno.getStatus());
System.out.println(retorno.getMotivo());
```

Se o webservice estiver ok, o resultado será:

```
107
Servico em operacao
```

Segue o link:

https://github.com/wmixvideo/nfe

Answer (score 5):

Me interessei pela sua pergunta porque há algum tempo fiz um projeto piloto de NFe usando Ruby e as informações são realmente mais difíceis de encontrar.

Olhando no site da Secretaria da Fazenda de SP, tem um emissor de NFe, feito em Java. http://www.emissornfe.fazenda.sp.gov.br/download_v2.html
Se você der uma olhada no manifesto do jnlp que ele baixa, tem várias bibliotecas (jars) que poderiam ser úteis.

Como aparentemente não funciona no Mac, não consegui investigar mais a fundo. Não sei se daria para baixar estes jars, se eles tem documentação e qual seria o tipo de licença.

É apenas um *pointer* pra você investigar.

Answer (score 3):

Provavelmente você já conheça o Projeto ACBr que é feito principalmente para Delphi. Eles tem um software executável (ACBr Monitor) que fica no SysTray da máquina e ficará aguardando comandos na sintaxe dos componentes ACBr. Por conta disso funciona em Java também.

Recomendo muito este projeto Open Source, para maiores informações do Monitor veja no site:

http://acbr.sourceforge.net/drupal/?q=node/19

No fórum você pode tirar as dúvidas que tiver sobre o assunto.

http://www.projetoacbr.com.br/forum/

Answer (score 0):

Olá! Se tiver nota de serviço envolvida e objetivo principal do seu software não é emitir notas, integre-o a um webservice de nota fiscal. 
Pois esse componente, principalmente NFSE, precisa de atualização contante, fora as inúmeras fezes que as prefeituras estão com todo tipo de problema e não assumem a culpa.
Atualmente utilizo e indico o www.enotasgw.com.br.
No caso de nota de produto indico o ACBR, pois é um projeto mais maduro e tem vários outros componentes que lhe podem ser uteis, como cupom fiscal e etc. A contra indicação é necessitar de servidor windows.