# Nota Fiscal Eletrônica em Java

Tags: java, nfe

Tenho um sistema web em java que faz controle da venda de produtos farmacêuticos e agora preciso implementar a NFe neste sistema. Gostaria de saber se existe algum curso, bibliotecas ou até mesmo algum exemplo onde posso me basear?

Comment: Manual de Integração da Versão 3.10: [Manual de Integração NFe 3.10](http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/Exibirarquivo.aspx?conteudo=F0KMG7669Uw=) .

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/234/biblioteca-java-para-nota-fiscal-eletr%C3%B4nica-nfe-brasileira