# Software NFe em java

Tags: java, nfe

Estou com um projeto para criar um emissor de NFe em Java... Mas o problema é que não tenho muita ideia e muito conhecimento para o desenvolvimento desse tipo de projeto. 
Alguem sabe se tem alguma biblioteca, paga ou gratuita, para desenvolver um emissor de NFe em java?
Achei esse projeto: https://github.com/fincatto/nfe
Queria saber se alguem ja chegou a usar ou a testar.. Ou é melhor fazer tudo na mão, do zero? 
Preciso ter uma ideia nisso, se alguém puder me ajudar, indicar algum tutorial ou alguma biblioteca... Preciso de preferencia desenvolver para Web. 
.

Comment: possível duplicata de [Biblioteca Java para Nota Fiscal Eletrônica (NFe) brasileira](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/234/biblioteca-java-para-nota-fiscal-eletr%c3%b4nica-nfe-brasileira)

Comment: henrique vê isto http://www.desenvolvedoresdaruma.com.br/home/index.php

Comment: @JorgeB. Daruma e' para NFe ou Cupom fiscal? Ja utilizou?

Comment: henrique NFe, NFCe, etc. Dá para tudo. Sim usei e é excelente.

Comment: @JorgeB. Vc usou o projeto exemplo que disponibilizam para usar nas suas aplicacoes? E e' possivel a autenticacao de certificado digital, geracao de XML e envio de nf por ele?

Comment: Usei o do PHP, mas suponho que o de Java seja parecido. Vê aqui como funciona: http://desenvolvedores.migrate.com.br/modulo-nf-e/

Comment: @JorgeB. Ah sim, esse link vc usou como base?

Comment: Sim, usei e foi bem simples de fazer.

Comment: ok, mais uma ultima duvida: A formatacao do xml e' feita automaticamente com o uso da biblioteca da daruma?