# NF-e Nota Fiscal Eletrônica com Grails

Tags: nfe, grails

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação comercial em Grails. Nesta aplicação vou precisar emitir Nota Fiscal Eletrônica (NF-e). Será que existe alguma API, biblioteca ou *plugin* que eu possa usar em Grails?

Sobre o documento em si conheço alguma coisa, pois já tenho aplicação feita em Delphi utilizando o componente AcBR, mas para a emissão de NFe em ambiente Web tô perdido.

Answer (score 1):

Como Grails tem integração total com Java, você pode utilizar qualquer biblioteca Java com essa finalidade. Dei uma buscada no Google, e cheguei nessa resposta [Biblioteca Java para Nota Fiscal Eletrônica (NFe) brasileira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/234/biblioteca-java-para-nota-fiscal-eletr%C3%B4nica-nfe-brasileira)

Existem várias alternativas. O jeito mais fácil de você incorporá-las em seu projeto, é ver se elas estão disponíveis em algum repositório maven, e ai inclulas em seu projeto Grails usando o BuildConfig.groovy (Grails 2) ou o build.gradle (Grails 3).

Não trabalhei ainda com nota fiscal eletrônica, então não sei te dizer quais das opções disponíveis no link acima que é a mais adequada. Achei também esse repositório, tem sido atualizado frequentemente, então também vale a pena dar uma olhada: https://github.com/Samuel-Oliveira/Java_NFe

Ele já está disponibilizado em repositório maven, então vai ser fácil você colocar no seu projeto. Se ficar com dúvidas em como incorporar no projeto Grails uma biblioteca, pergunte aqui que te ajudo, só precisarei saber qual versão do Grails vocês está usando. Abraços.

Comment: Obrigado @Bruno pela resposta. Eu já havia visto as bibliotecas  jNFE, JeNiFEr e Caelum-Stella. Estes projetos pararam na versão 2.0 da NFe, hoje estamos na versão 3.10 e já foi liberada a versão 4.0 no ambiente de homologação do Sefaz.
Este repositório realmente está bem atualizado: https://github.com/Samuel-Oliveira/Java_NFe
Também encontrei este outro: https://github.com/wmixvideo/nfe

Comment: se puder me ajudar eu agradeço. Estou usando a versão 2.5.3 do Grails.

Comment: Para adicionar uma dependência no Grails 3.X.X, você tem que adicionar no bloco dependencies do arquivo build.gradle desse modo:

 compile "com.github.wmixvideo:nfe:2.0.2"

Ai já terá acesso a biblioteca do link que você comentou.

Já no caso de acessar a biblioteca Java_NFe, você precisará adicionar duas linhas. A primeira é o repositório, dentro da sessão repositories:

maven {
    url "http://www.autocomsistemas.com.br:8081/nexus/content/repositories/autocom/"
}

Depois a biblioteca, semelhante a anterior (bloco dependencies):
compile "br.com.samuelweb:java-nfe:3.10.8"

Comment: Fiz um teste com Grails 3.3.0 conforme o @Bruno mencionou.
No build.gradle adicionei a linha com o repositório: maven { url "http://www.autocomsistemas.com.br:8081/nexus/content/repositories/autocom/"
Em dependências, adicionei a linha: compile "br.com.samuelweb:java-nfe:3.10.8" - Efetuei um teste de Status do Sefaz RJ, funcionou!

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia

Nunca mechi com  nfe no grails mais bem  basicamente pela versão que  vc esta usando é so baixar a lib que vai usar e colocar o jar na pasta libs que vc vai conseguir usar todos os recursos dela  no seu projeto.  a wiki essa lib java_nfe e bem completa https://github.com/Samuel-Oliveira/Java_NFe/wiki   talvez resolva teu problema

Comment: No Grails 2.5.3 consegui efetuar uma consulta do status do sefaz, coloquei o .jar do projeto na pasta lib e deu certinho. 
Fui fazer um teste com o Grais 3.2.7, não  reconhece a lib java_nfe. Já referenciei nas dependências ( runtime fileTree(dir: 'src/main/groovy', include: 'java-nfe-3.10.8.jar') e nem todos os métodos são reconhecidos.